# Can't update UITextView size after setting content height

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

What I need is license agreement to be shown up on the first launch of application. Simple UITextView with with agree button after text. I need that its size to be equal screen size and content could be scrollable. All this happens in ViewDidLoad() method in main ViewController:

```
let text = "<p>very very long html text</p>"

var str = NSAttributedString()
do {
   str = try NSAttributedString(data: text.dataUsingEncoding 
   (NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
   options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], 
   documentAttributes: nil)   
   }
   catch 
   {
       print(error)
   }

   let licenseView = UITextView(frame:CGRectMake(self.navigationController!.view.frame.origin.x,self.navigationController!.view.frame.origin.y, self.navigationController!.view.frame.size.width, self.navigationController!.view.frame.size.height))
   licenseView.attributedText = str

   licenseView.scrollEnabled = true
   licenseView.editable = false
   licenseView.selectable = true
   licenseView.dataDetectorTypes = .All

   let LVSize:CGSize = licenseView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(licenseView.frame.size.width, CGFloat(FLT_MAX)))
```

licenseView' content height is 1850.5. Need to add button with y position which equals to 1850.5.

```
   let button = UIButton(frame:CGRectMake(0, LVSize.height, 300, 50))
   button.setTitle("Agree", forState: .Normal)
   button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
   licenseView.addSubview(button)
```

now we need to resize content to make button visible after text

```
   licenseView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(licenseView.frame.size.width, LVSize.height+300)
   licenseView.setNeedsDisplay()
   licenseView.layoutIfNeeded()


   self.navigationController!.view.addSubview(licenseView)
```

The problem is that contentSize is changed(if I `print(licenseView.contentSize)` it will output `(320.0, 2150.5)`), but the textView still behave like its content height is 1850.5 - when I scroll down I see that button is outside of scrollable area. What I've missed?

Comment: Assign the contentsize of the textview before you adding the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's seems that when I called `licenseView.layoutIfNeeded()` layoutSubviews() in UITextView reseted contentSize to the size of text. I don't know what logic it uses exactly

I could solve my problem with writing custom class based on UITextView and overwriting layoutSubviews method but I solved the problem with this:

```
licenseView.contentInset.bottom = button.frame.size.height
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it if you have `AutoLayout` in your storyboard. You need to create outlet of your height and width constraints.

```
@IBOutlet weak var height: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var width: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Now you can change it as your wish by assigning constant value to it

```
width.constant = 400
height.constant = 200
```

Hope this could help you!!

Comment: Once you added `UITextView` as **subView** then it is not possible to update layout of it

Comment: FYI, you can call `setNeedsLayout`, then `layoutIfNeeded` to update.